# How to subset a remote tbl in r?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, dplyr, rpostgresql

I have loaded a sql table to a tbl using dplyr (rr is my db connection)  :

```
s_log=rr%>%tbl("s_log")
```

then extracted three columns and put them in a new tbl :

```
id_date_amount=s_log%>%select(id,created_at,amount)
```

when i run head (id_date_amount) it works properly:

```
      id              created_at                amount
1   34101           2016-07-20 10:41:23          19750
2   11426           2016-07-20 10:38:15          19750
3   26694           2016-07-20 10:38:18          49750
4   25656           2016-07-20 10:42:05          49750
5   23987           2016-07-20 10:40:31          19750
6   24564           2016-07-20 10:38:35          19750
```

now , i need to filter the id_date_amount in a way that it only contains the past 21 days:

```
filtered_ADP=subset(id_date_payment,as.Date('2016-08-22')- as.Date(created_at) > 0 & as.Date('2016-08-22')- as.Date(created_at)<=21)
```

i get the following error:

```
Error in as.Date(created_at) : object 'created_at' not found
```

i think that's because i don't have id_date_payment locally , but how can i shape that subset to sent it to id_date_payment and get back the results?

i tried using deployer::filter :

```
id_date_amount=id_date_amount %>% filter( as.Date('2016-08-22') - as.Date(created_at) > 0 & as.Date('2016-08-22')- as.Date(created_at)<=21 )
```

but i get this error :

```
   Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax      error at or near "AS"
LINE 3: WHERE "status" = 'success' AND AS.DATE('2016-08-22') - AS.DA...
                                   ^
)
```

Comment: If you're using dplyr, use dplyr verbs, i.e. `filter`.

Comment: @alistaire If you see the question, i made an edit, filter is not working as well

Comment: @dww appreciate your help

Comment: @Forrens R. Stevens appreciate your help

Comment: The error message reads as though it doesn't like the syntax of what you passed to filter.  Try a simpler filter, and see if that works.

Comment: @ Richie Cotton filter works for the other columns properly

Comment: Since I can't reproduce, it's hard to say exactly what is going wrong.  Try `filter(as.Date('2016-08-22') - as.Date(created_at) > 0, as.Date('2016-08-22')- as.Date(created_at)<=21 )`.